# is it acceptable to do pairewise comparisons for mixed regressions that aren't independent?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, multiple-comparisons, lm

I have a model specified as `lmer(log(dv) ~ chosen*tasktype +(1|id)+(1|qs), data)`

The key issue in the data is that the groups are not indepedent, i.e.,  `id` and `qs` partially overlapping in fixed effects. This why I do lme rather than ANOVA, as suggested in a paper.

I want to know the difference between group levels so did pairewise comparisons using `emmeans`, but then I wonder if it is valid with those random effects?